# html buttons created dynamically don't respond to onclick like the other regular buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a regular button created in a regular html form as:

```
<button id="create-booking">New Booking</button>
```

And an event associated to it as:

```
  $("#create-booking").button().on("click", function() {
          dialog.dialog("open");
      });
```

Which works totally fine.

But if I create a button through php (because the button only appears when a MySQL record is populated inside a table) then I would create it as this:

```
printf("<button class='del'>Delete</button>");
```

So I apply the function to it...

```
$(".del").button().on("click", function() {
          alert("hi, test");
      });
```

And it doesn't work at all. You click it and it just does nothing.

What's the difference between both cases? Aren't they exactly the same?

Comment: The browser won't be aware of how the page source was generated, so I expect the problem lies elsewhere.  Keep in mind that while your page is being processed, `$` can only see what's already been drawn.  So make sure your `$(".del")` is either in a `<script>` element *below* your button, or triggered with `document.ready` or somesuch.

Comment: try delegation maybe that will fix it

Comment: The one you created yourself uses `id` and the other example uses `class`  I'm guessing that's where your problem is.

Comment: @nomistic That's a good point.  Not sure if jquery's `.button` can attach to multiple elements.  Perhaps simply try `$(".del").click(function() { ..etc.. });`

Comment: I tried your suggestions, for the moment the problem still persist. I have the jquery and the php in different files. I wonder if is relevant which file finishes loading sooner. It could be that the php has finished loading and the jquery still not, therefore php won't receive the attributes passed via jquery? That part confuses me a bit.

Comment: @SuperJer You were right, at the end I did some more testing, I changed the code to a `<script>` below the button and it worked fine. If you feel like typing an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I've added the answer.  It may be helpful for other folks in the future if you reword your question so that it does not point to PHP as the problem.  This case is strictly a DOM/Javascript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be that your `<button>` isn't available in the DOM before the related javascript fires.  Make sure that:

**1)** If your javascript is contained in a separate script file that it's wrapped in a `document.ready` or similar like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".del").click(function() { ..etc.. });
});
```

**2)** If your javascript is contained in the same file as your `<button>` that its `<script>` element comes *after* your `<button>`